# Return only unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get counts of how many jobs were done, regardless of personnel working on them. What I need to do is filter out any duplicates, the catch is that the entire row isn't duplicate so DISTINCT won't work here. I want to filter out if there is any duplication based on JobCode, JobType TaskTime and day of week. So my table looks like the following:

```
JobCode JobType TaskTime    EmployeeID  M   Tu  W   Th  F   Sa  Su
==================================================================
1800    1       06:49       101         1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1800    1       06:49       102         1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1800    1       07:04       101         1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1800    1       07:26       101         1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1800    1       07:49       101         1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1800    2       15:55       101         1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1800    1       16:20       101         1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1800    1       16:50       101         1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1800    2       16:55       101         1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

My SQL Query is like this

```
SELECT t1.JobCode, t1.JobType,  
    t1.M, t1.Tu, t1.W, t1.Th, t1.F, t1.Sa, t1.Su,
    SUM(t1.M + t1.Tu + t1.W + t1.Th + t1.F + t1.Sa + t1.Su) as Totals
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table1 AS t1_overlap ON
    t1_overlap.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID AND
    t1_overlap.JobType = t1.JobType AND
    t1_overlap.TaskTime = t1.TaskTime
    AND 
    (
    (t1.M = 1 AND t1_overlap.M = t1.M) OR
    (t1.Tu = 1 AND t1_overlap.Tu = t1.Tu) OR
    (t1.W = 1 AND t1_overlap.W = t1.W) OR
    (t1.Th = 1 AND t1_overlap.Th = t1.Th) OR
    (t1.F = 1 AND t1_overlap.F = t1.F) OR
    (t1.Sa = 1 AND t1_overlap.Sa = t1.Sa) OR
    (t1.Su = 1 AND t1_overlap.Su = t1.Su)
    )
GROUP BY t1.JobCode, t1.JobType, t1.M, t1.Tu, t1.W, t1.Th, t1.F, t1.Sa, t1.Su
```

The data returned is like this

```
JobCode JobType M   Tu  W   Th  F   Sa  Su  Totals
==================================================
1800    1       1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1800    1       1   1   1   1   1   0   0   30
1800    2       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   10
```

What I want to see is only unique values, so I don't want that first line that shows the job was worked on by employee 102 on only M because I'm already seeing that employee 101 worked on that same job on that same day and time. So what I want to see instead is the following:

```
JobCode JobType M   Tu  W   Th  F   Sa  Su  Totals
==================================================
1800    1       1   1   1   1   1   0   0   30
1800    2       1   1   1   1   1   0   0   10
```

Really I don't need to see the days of the week, I'm just showing them here so I can see whats being returned. All I actually need to see for output is the JobCode, JobType and Totals like the following:

```
JobCode JobType Totals
======================
1800    1       30
1800    2       10
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How come employee 101 is preferred over 102? How come their "1" doesn't figure into the total for that Jobcode/type? What's the logic here?

Comment: @SeanLange Please don't just redirect me to the main page of a different forum, that's not a helpful answer at all. I have searched several places before posting here, just haven't found quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Oops....that is because I posted the wrong link. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @JNevill the EmployeeID really doesn't matter. What I'm trying to see is a count of time when an employee worked on a task. I don't want the count to increase when 1, 2, 3, etc employees did. I just need to get a count of occurrences that a given task was worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a quick subquery where you grab the max of each day, grouping by your key, then sum the results, would do the trick:

```
SELECT
    jobcode,
    jobtype,
    sum(monday+tuesday+wednesday+thursday+friday+saturday+sunday) AS total
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            jobcode,
            jobtype,
            tasktime,
            max(m) as monday,
            max(tu) as tuesday,
            max(w) as wednesday,
            max(th) as thursday,
            max(f) as friday,
            max(sa) as saturday,
            max(su) as sunday
        FROM Table1 T1
        GROUP BY jobcode, jobtype, tasktime
    ) t2
GROUP BY jobcode, jobtype
```

There may be something more eloquent than that, but this should get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
;With cte1
as
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PArtition by t1.JobCode,t1.JobType order by t1.JobCode,t1.JobType) RNO,t1.JobCode, t1.JobType,
    SUM(t1.M + t1.Tu + t1.W + t1.Th + t1.F + t1.Sa + t1.Su) OVER(partition by t1.JobCode,t1.JobType ORDER BY t1.JobCode,t1.JobType ) as Totals
FROM Table1 AS t1
JOIN Table1 AS t1_overlap ON
    t1_overlap.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID AND
    t1_overlap.JobType = t1.JobType AND
    t1_overlap.TaskTime = t1.TaskTime
    AND 
    (
    (t1.M = 1 AND t1_overlap.M = t1.M) OR
    (t1.Tu = 1 AND t1_overlap.Tu = t1.Tu) OR
    (t1.W = 1 AND t1_overlap.W = t1.W) OR
    (t1.Th = 1 AND t1_overlap.Th = t1.Th) OR
    (t1.F = 1 AND t1_overlap.F = t1.F) OR
    (t1.Sa = 1 AND t1_overlap.Sa = t1.Sa) OR
    (t1.Su = 1 AND t1_overlap.Su = t1.Su)
    ))

    SELECT t1.JobCode, t1.JobType,Totals
    FROM cte1
    WHERE RNO=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can use the super-awesome `ROW_NUMBER` function and wrap the query so that you effectively 1) define a grouping, and 2) take ONLY the first row of each group. Look closely at the `over (partition by ... order by ...)` clause to understand how you can control the grouping and the "ranking" (which ones you want to make it through to the results).

```
select JobCode, JobType, Totals
from (
    SELECT t1.JobCode, t1.JobType, SUM(t1.M + t1.Tu + t1.W + t1.Th + t1.F + t1.Sa + t1.Su) as Totals
           ,row_number() over (partition by t1.JobCode order by t1.JobType) as rseq
    FROM Table1 AS t1
    JOIN Table1 AS t1_overlap ON
        t1_overlap.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID AND
        t1_overlap.JobType = t1.JobType AND
        t1_overlap.TaskTime = t1.TaskTime
        AND 
        (
        (t1.M = 1 AND t1_overlap.M = t1.M) OR
        (t1.Tu = 1 AND t1_overlap.Tu = t1.Tu) OR
        (t1.W = 1 AND t1_overlap.W = t1.W) OR
        (t1.Th = 1 AND t1_overlap.Th = t1.Th) OR
        (t1.F = 1 AND t1_overlap.F = t1.F) OR
        (t1.Sa = 1 AND t1_overlap.Sa = t1.Sa) OR
        (t1.Su = 1 AND t1_overlap.Su = t1.Su)
        )
    GROUP BY t1.JobCode, t1.JobType, t1.M, t1.Tu, t1.W, t1.Th, t1.F, t1.Sa, t1.Su
) x
where rseq = 1 --filter to keep only the "first" row (JobType) for each JobCode
```

Note that the comments about "how do you decide which one to keep" are valid, and this example assumes you want to see "one row per JobCode", and keep the "first JobType for that JobCode".  This can be adjusted to fit, if you'll explain the logic you want to use a little more clearly.